# Script error in JQuery

Tags: jquery

i am getting script error in Jquery. please suggest how to resolve this. Script error message displayed is  **"****HTML parsing error:** unable to modify the parent container element before the child element closed**".**
**code:0**   **line:0**  **char:0**. My Jquery  code is:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

     (function($) {
     var search=window.location.search.substring(1);
     var page=search.split("=");
     var location=window.location.toString();
     var url=location.split('?')[0];         

     if(page[1]=='custDetails'){

       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#message').dialog('open');
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#pop').click(function(){
      $('#message').dialog('open');
       return false;
         });
       });
      });
     }   // end of if      
        else {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pop').click(function(){
        $('#message').dialog('open');
        return false;
          });
        });

        }  // end of else

        $('#message').dialog({
        width:200,
        autoOpen:false,
        buttons:{ 
           Close:function() {
       $ (this.dialog('close');
       $ ('#message').replaceWith('url');
                 }
              } 
          });

       $('#page').click((function(event){            
         window.print();
          });

        })  ($);
      </script>
```

when i remove **$('#message').dialog({});**  component it doesn't throw script error. please suggest me the cause.

Comment: ...and include the error message.

Comment: Why do you have so many `$(document).ready` event handlers? One would suffice.

Comment: If you formatted your code, errors would be easier to spot.

Comment: I am downvoting simply because this is just so badly done from such a basic stand point - I know that is not totally in the spirit of this site and I never do this but gee...

Comment: @Jørgen , i got this error message.  "HTML parsing error: unable to modify the parent container element before the child element closed". code:0 line:0 char:0

Comment: @ James Allardice , Thanks for response. As i am newbie in s/w developement and the code above is existing and i am just fixing that script error. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax errors here:

```
$('#message').dialog($
    width: 200;
    autoOpen: false;
    buttons. {
    close: function() {
        $(this.dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$('#page').click((function(event) {
    window.print();
});
```

Try this:

```
$('#message').dialog({
    width: 200,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        close: function() {
            $(this.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#page').click(function(event) {
    window.print();
});
```

Comment: thanks epignosisx, still it is  showing script error  until i don't remove

Comment: @user1057697 you have one more syntax error. Look for the line $ (this.dialog('close'); It should be $(this).dialog('close'); You should try http://www.jslint.com/. It will identify this sort of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Full of syntax errors ...

```
$('#message').dialog($  // << ERROR 1 should be {
        width:200; // << ERROR 2 the ; should be ,
        autoOpen:false; // << ERROR 3 the ; should be ,
        buttons.{close:function() { // << ERROR 4 the . should be :
       $ (this.dialog('close'); // << ERROR 5 the $(this should be $(this).
          }}
         });
```

all together it should be

```
    $('#message').dialog({
        width:200,
        autoOpen:false,
        buttons: { close:function() {
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                         }
                 }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is there, are you sure you included jQueryui js file?Something like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after you included your jQuery js file?